# Python upgrade issue from 3.9 to 3.10 on Windows

Tags: python, windows

I had a Python 3.9 installed on my Windows 10 machine and it had a lot of issues, so I had to upgrade it to Python 3.10

I uninstalled Python 3.9 from my machine, and installed 3.10, and added it to PATH.

I also had a Python 3.7 instance as well.

Now after installing Python 3.10, pip and virtualenv are not working anymore, when I try to install virtualenv using pip, I get this error:

```
Fatal error in launcher: Unable to create process using '"c:\users\wwwwww\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\python.exe"  "C:\Users\wwwww\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\Scripts\pip.exe" install virtualenv': File not found
```

Even after uninstalling Python 3.9, I can still see 3.7 and 3.9 on my machine:

[image]

When I try python on my Visual Code terminal, I get the shell and everything works fine:
[image]

But when I try to run it on Git Bash, I get nothing, and the terminal crashes:
[image]

I want to reset everything and remove all python and pip so I can start from scratch and continue my work because I'm blocked right now.

Comment: if you installed Python10 why do you try to use Python3.7? I would assume - nothing was wrong with 3.9 as well on your pc. its just the set up needs to be done a  way you intend to use it and than used it that way. because you can choose which python is added to path and used as default, which one you should call explicitly and mainly you should be working certain per project specific venv not using system default python for everything

Comment: virtual env uses python3.7 not python3.10 (`\python37\python.exe"`

Comment: I know I am not trying to use any version, I just do pip install virtualenv. I want to uninstall all previous versions but I can't find them anywhere. I get this error because I went ahead and looked for the folder where Python39 is and deleted it, but I can't find 3.7

Comment: I have added 3.10 to my PATH variables, one was automatically added during installation, and the other one I added it manually because it asked me to do when I tried to install pip manually using get-pip.py

Comment: if you run pip install, you are trying to use default python and that's 3.7 - that's how you have chosen to set it up. You should never use pip install it should be python -m pip...  then you will also know which python you are running.

Comment: I suggest checking some youtube on setting up python dev machine; sorry if its sounds nasty, but from all that you have posted its clear that nothing is wrong with your pc, python 3.7, 3.9, or 3.10; the wrong part is that you have not set it up a way you would like to work with it and now you are confused also you are lacking some basics, like venv, etc. I suggest you first think of which should be default Python, properly install all the versions your need, uninstall not needed versions; then configure venv for your project.

Comment: ok I tried python -m and it worked, but it's too long, I just wanna do what I always do: pip install, what can I do to get rid of this python 37?

Comment: I also have to do python -m virtualenv ... instead of virtualenv... I don't like this

Comment: I know about venv buddy, my problem is not the venv, my problem is Python, which is installed inside any venv I create, I have like 100 venvs for many projects in my laptop, and I've been working with this for years, my problem is Microsoft Windows and its issues with Python versions and path variables. My issue is simple, My Windows knows Python 3.7, so it's there somewhere, I wanna remove it, it is as simple as that, how can your OS look for a package that is not anywhere to find???? Maybe I should go somewhere and change some value for it to look in the right direction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is with Windows 10 and their decision to automatically enable Python as an execution alias, and thus impacting the command line behavior.

To solve this issue, simply go to Windows Parameters -> Apps and Features, and search: Manage Apps Execution Aliases.

Uncheck every Python mention in the list:
[image]

And now the problem is solved:

[image]